# Jasmine: Set controller property on initialization, angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, ecmascript-6

Controller

```
function SomeController(someService) {
  const $ctrl = this;

  activate();

  function activate() {
    someService.retrieveSomeData($ctrl.criteria).then(doSomething);
  }

  function doSomething(response) {
    $ctrl.result = response.data;
  }
}
```

Test

```
describe('SomeController', () => {

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  let $controller;

  beforeEach(inject((_$controller_,) => {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

 it('tests $controller properties', () => {
    const $scope = {};
    const controller = $controller('SomeController', { $scope });
  });
});
```

Here I want to sent `$ctrl.criteria` while initializing my controller so I can test `$ctrl.result` afterwards.

Comment: you could just have `const controller = $controller('SomeController')` where `controller` will have `this` available

Comment: As you can see, the activate() method executes on initialization, I tried setting it after initialization, but the activate() method is already fired by then.

Comment: @AbubakrDar is this a component's controller?

Comment: No, its not @SiddharthPandey. It is used to show a customized $mdDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if its a general solution or specific to this case, but to pass in the locals of a controller, you have the third aurgument of $controller.
At least, it worked for me.

Test

```
describe('SomeController', () => {

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  let $controller;

  beforeEach(inject((_$controller_,) => {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

 it('tests $controller properties', () => {
    const $scope = {};
    const criteria = {id: 1};
    const controller = $controller('SomeController', { $scope }, { criteria });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm amazed that I couldn't find this in any documentation or any of the easily available content. Such a simple solution. Wasted hours on it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
describe('SomeController', () => {

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  let $controller;

  beforeEach(inject((_$controller_,) => {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

 it('tests $controller properties', () => {
    const scope = {
      criteria : {id: 1}
    };
    const controller = $controller('SomeController', { $scope : scope });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing that, but criteria was still undefined.

Comment: What I figured out was, you pass in the controller properties as a third argument.